# Angular lite-server results in viewing a blank page

Tags: angular, lite-server

I have a Single page application and I want to run my application with a lite-server.

This is my bs-config

[image]

The problem is as follows when I run the lite-server and browse to my localhost:3000; the only thing I see is a blank page.

It looks like the lite-server loads my index page but can't seem to find my routing to the home page etc.

I know my application works perfectly when I start with npm start.

But I want to use a lite server for some test purposes.

This is how I start my server: "lite-server": "lite-server" (npm run lite-server)

What I've tried:

- Use other paths.
- Add a specific index HTML page.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Build the application using `ng build` and run lite-server on `dist/<project-name>` folder because that contains final `index.html`.

Comment: This was something I forgot to describe in my question.

I already did the ng build and changed the baseDir name, but I still get the blank page.

Comment: I also try to do it, but it doesn't help me.